# can, may, or will - their difference

Tags: modal-verbs

I'm wondering how "can" differs from "may" and "will" in the following sentence.

I am confident a solution **can** be found.

Particularly puzzling is the fact that "can" and "may" both indicate possibility.

"Will" has a definitive flavor to it, but "Can" seems to have it too.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Try looking the words up in a dictionary and select the meanings that you think would work. If you are not sure, add the details of your research to your question.

Comment: I don't think any dictionaries explain the difference between "can" and "may" when they refer to possibility.

Comment: Some grammar books say "can" indicate general possibility. But the sentence in question is about something specific.

Comment: I wouldn't bother too much about the relative "degree of uncertainty" regarding ***can*** or ***may*** in your example context. It's more useful to simply note that using ***may*** in such constructions is dated / formal / stilted today, and best avoided entirely.

Comment: Is there any other difference apart from "may" sounding more dated / formal?

Answer (score 1):

While both *can* and *may* are used to express possibility (according to Cambridge dictionary), *may* is less certain.

Compare:

1. *There **may** be other problems that we don't know about.* (maybe there are some problems but maybe there are no problems at all)
2. *I **may** see you tomorrow before I leave.* (there is some possibility but I am not sure)
3. *You **can** get stamps from the local newsagents.* (if you go there, you will get stamps because it's a fact that they are sold there)
4. *Smoking **can** cause cancer.* (it's just a fact that it's possible for you to develop cancer if you smoke)

So, in your sentence "I am confident a solution can be found" *can* shows a higher degree of possibility. In fact, *can* is better than *may* here because "I am confident".

If you say "I am confident a solution **will** be found", you mean that you are sure the solution will be found in the future.